# prevent new windows webbrowser control

Tags: c#, webbrowser-control

I'm trying to use webbrowser control on console app (dll)

i want to prevent it from opening up new window.

```
using (WebBrowser wb = new WebBrowser())
    {

                    wb.ScrollBarsEnabled = false;
                    wb.ScriptErrorsSuppressed = true;
           wb.NewWindow += new System.ComponentModel.CancelEventHandler(wb_NewWindow);        
                   wb.Navigate(url);
            while (wb.ReadyState != WebBrowserReadyState.Complete)
            {
                Application.DoEvents();
            }
  }



private void wb_NewWindow(object sender, CancelEventArgs e)
        {
            //System.Windows.Forms.HtmlDocument document =
            //    this.webBrowser1.Document;

                       e.Cancel = true; 

        }
```

Comment: it keeps popping up new windows while loading data

Comment: @namvo you mean like the extra adz windows? third party websites ?